# Google Drive API (Python) - Файл скачивается без формата расширения (.mp4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, google-drive

Проблема в том, что когда я загружаю видео на Диск и получаю ссылку на скачивание:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=*******************&export=download
```

Файл скачивается без формата .mp4.
Просто файл и если дописать .mp4 все работает, но так же не должно быть.
А если файл вручную залить на Диск и такой же ссылкой скачать, но все нормально.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: файл забираете `requests`?

Comment: Как именно файл скачиваете? Обычно информация о имени файла (вместе с разрешением) находится в заголовке ответа `Content-Disposition`.